# How do I change the timesteps of a CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, conv-neural-network

If I have train and test sets as so (samples, timesteps, features):

```
Train: (300, 7, 7)
Test: (46, 7, 7)
```

This means I have 7 timesteps. However, I need 30. What are the steps I need to take to make this change?

I am aware that my dataset needs to be a size that's a multiple of 30 for this change, but it's already 2100 as preparation for this (both a multiple of 7 and 30).

Answer (score 0):

Use the numpy package :

example:

```
>> x = np.zeros([300,7,7])
>> x.shape                                                                                          
  (300, 7, 7)
>> newShape = x.reshape(-1,30,30)
```

in your case, return error because size (300, 7, 7) is 14700 elements. In fact:

```
   >>  x.reshape(-1).shape                                                                             
   >> (14700,)
```